# Javascript - get element from page click it. getElementsByClassName not working

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, browser-automation

So I'm trying to get a button element from the page by the class name. But this function, as well as queryselector return undefined value. What might be the reason? Can it be because this element is a child of another element?

```
var checkout_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('button-submit');
console.log("INITIALIZED"); 
console.log(checkout_btn);
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opx0x.png)

[Button html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gosma.png)

Comment: use queries to select, `var btn = document.querySelector(".button-submit");`

Comment: The code you posted is OK, it isn't the problem. We can't help because we don't have enough information. If I have to guess, just stay sure you're executing it once the DOM is loaded. You can also put it at the end of the page, just before `</body>` tag.

Comment: @TudorAlexandru Tried it. Same result.

Comment: @kosmos I just put it in window.onload function. Same thing happens. Also I'm doing it through a content script for chrome extension, maybe it's the reason? Another weird thing is that if I find elements by button tag it finds the element I need, but when I access it with a subscript it says null.

Answer (score -1):

create and use the ID instead of className or try this document.getElementsByClassName("button-submit")[0]

p.s. Because getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Comment: I can't create an Id, it's for a chrome extension which executes a content script on someone else's web site.

Comment: so try the 2nd one, with className[0]